# generic conv implementation only supprts NHWC tensor format for now

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I've installed `Python 2.7` but I'm receiving a `pickle protocol error`. I'm using a pre-trained style `GAN NVIDIA` for my project. I need help regarding this issue.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4JZ0.jpg)

Comment: Can you please provide the error you receive?

Comment: Error is in the attached pic